Draw line cross multiple column in Flutter

I want to draw something like this in flutter and I want this to be dynamic because the payments could be more than 3.
Also, to make sure that the payments, due date and indicator are aligned I thought of putting these three elements in one column and placing the three columns in one row. Now i'm stuck and I don’t know how to make the line cross the three dots without exceeding the sides and with a dynamic width.
This is what i've done since now:
Stack(
  children: [
    Positioned(
      bottom: 5, 
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      child: Container(
        height: 2, 
        color: AppColors.uiGrayscale500, 
      ),
    ),
    Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      children: [
        ...[0,1,2,3].map(
          (payment) {
            return Column(
              children: [
                Text(
                  'due date'
                ),
                Text(
                  'amount'
                ),
                    Container(
                      width: 12,
                      height: 12,
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                        color: Colors.red
                      ),
                )
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
),

Could please someone help me?

I set up a quick minimal repro on https://dartpad.dev/?id=259c5a49b09b97bf51d2d4fe716efd35. I'm not sure how to render the widget the way you want, but hopefully the Dartpad repro helps more people look at it.

do those 3 columns have the same width? for example if screen width is 480 do all columns have width == 160?

well, i think. it could be like this but i thought about dividing the screen by payment installments already! if you got some interesting solutions show me!

that's perfect! thank you so much, and also i really loved the way you code, thank you again @pskink

sure, your welcome
